# Confirm Password in Oracle Application Express

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, change-password

I have a form in Application Express where I let the user edit their details, update their password etc.

I would like to use the usual method of having the user type in their password twice and make sure the two passwords are typed identically so I can be sure they have have not made a mistake typing.

However, since both elements are form fields on the same page I can't see a way to compare them. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You could add a Validation that checks they are identical, e.g. if `:P1_PASSWORD = :P1_PASSWORD_VERIFY`

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried Jeffrey but it won't validate them.  I am wondering if the validations are server side rather than client side so it is not comparing what is typed but what is stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, validations are done on the server when the page is posted. If you want it to validate without posting you could use a dynamic action instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with checking they are identical during the submit you can simply do this in a page validation.
Let's say you have `P1_NEW_PASSWORD` and `P1_NEW_PASSWORD_CONFIRM`.
Then in the page processing box expand 'Validating', right click 'Validations' and choose 'Create'.
Choose 'Page Item', P1_NEW_PASSWORD, choose a name and as validation type choose 'PL/SQL', then 'PL/SQL Expression'. Enter `:P1_NEW_PASSWORD = :P1_NEW_PASSWORD_CONFIRM` as Validation Code, and choose an error message. Now create your validation.

Now when you try to submit the page and the passwords don't match, you will get an error message.